# MFC: CCombobox SetCursel incorrect

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, ccombobox

I have a trouble with `SetCurSel` of MFC.

My combobox has data like this: a, b, c, shop10, shop1, c, d.

I add data for combobox like that, then set cursel is Shop1

```
m_cbb.AddString(_T("a"));
m_cbb.AddString(_T("b"));
m_cbb.AddString(_T("shop10"));
m_cbb.AddString(_T("shop1"));
m_cbb.AddString(_T("c"));
m_cbb.AddString(_T("d"));

//m_cbb.SetWindowText(_T("shop1"));
m_cbb.SetCurSel(3);
UpdateData(FALSE);
```

It show Shop1 correct, but when I show combobox, cursel is Shop10.

[image: Cursel incorrect]

What is my mistake?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should add more details to your question and *show your code as text, not as an image*. But, from what I can see, the dropdown selection is being set to the first match for the current edit selection, and "shop1" matches the first part of the "shop10" string.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have edited my question, is there anyway to cursel at Shop1 in that case?

Comment: The interesting thing about combo boxes is that the text need have no relation to the items in the list, unless you use the `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` style.

Comment: Oh, I changed combobox style to CBS_DROPDOWNLIST and it's fixed my problem. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: It is also a flaw in the combo boilerplate code. The way it is designed means that it selects the first match (and shop1 is first matched my shop10 in the list), Something you need to be aware of at times.

Comment: If you want to select the item which text is "Shop1", you will need to do: `int index = m_cbb.FindStringExact(L"Shop1"); if (index != CB_ERR) m_cbb.SetCursel(index);`